# Why is my ggplot not plotting all of my data, specifically for "Browsing" and "Deciding How to buy"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When you look at my ggplot, there are a few areas it is not plotting my data.
Specifically, one of these areas is "Browsing" filled with "Execution". Another is "Deciding How to Buy" filled with "Execution". There is count data for these, but they are not being plotted.

Here is my dput(df):

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Journey.Area = c("Installing", "Using Product", 
"Installing", "Delivery", "Installing", "Delivery", "Installing", 
"Using Product", "Browsing", "Browsing", "Browsing", "Buying", 
"Delivery", "Delivery", "Installing", "Deciding How to Buy", 
"Installing", "Installing", "Delivery", "Buying", "Delivery", 
"Installing", "Browsing", "Installing", "Delivery", "Installing", 
"Installing", "Deciding How to Buy", "Installing", "Browsing", 
"Delivery", "Installing", "Browsing", "Installing", "Browsing", 
"Deciding How to Buy", "Installing", "Anticipating", "Delivery", 
"Delivery", "Deciding How to Buy", "Installing", "Using Product", 
"Installing", "Delivery", "Installing", "Installing", "Deciding How to Buy", 
"Delivery", "Delivery", "Delivery", "Browsing", "Using Product", 
"Deciding How to Buy", "Delivery", "Installing", "Installing", 
"Deciding How to Buy", "Installing", "Installing", "Anticipating", 
"Installing", "Deciding How to Buy", "Deciding How to Buy", "Installing", 
"Browsing", "Delivery", "Pickup", "Anticipating", "Deciding How to Buy", 
"Using Product", "Installing", "Anticipating", "Deciding How to Buy", 
"Browsing", "Deciding How to Buy", "Buying", "Delivery", "Installing", 
"Installing", "Installing", "Deciding How to Buy", "Anticipating", 
"Delivery", "Installing", "Anticipating", "Delivery", "Delivery", 
"Delivery", "Anticipating", "Browsing", "Deciding How to Buy", 
"Deciding How to Buy", "Anticipating", "Deciding How to Buy", 
"Delivery", "Delivery", "Deciding How to Buy", "Deciding How to Buy", 
"Deciding How to Buy"), Experience.Framework = c("People/Associate", 
"Execution", "People/Associate", "Execution", "People/Associate", 
"People/Associate", "Execution", "Execution", "People/Associate", 
"People/Associate", "People/Associate", "Systems", "Execution", 
"People/Associate", "Execution", "Process/Policy", "People/Associate", 
"People/Associate", "Execution", "Process/Policy", "Execution", 
"Execution", "People/Associate", "Execution", "Execution", "Execution", 
"Execution", "Process/Policy", "Execution", "Systems", "Execution", 
"Execution", "People/Associate", "Execution", "Execution", "Process/Policy", 
"Execution", "Systems", "Execution", "Process/Policy", "Process/Policy", 
"Execution", "Execution", "Execution", "Execution", "People/Associate", 
"Execution", "Execution", "Execution", "Execution", "Execution", 
"People/Associate", "Execution", "Process/Policy", "Execution", 
"People/Associate", "People/Associate", "People/Associate", "Execution", 
"People/Associate", "Process/Policy", "Execution", "Execution", 
"Execution", "Execution", "Systems", "Execution", "Execution", 
"Execution", "Systems", "Execution", "People/Associate", "Execution", 
"Execution", "People/Associate", "People/Associate", "Systems", 
"Execution", "Execution", "People/Associate", "Execution", "People/Associate", 
"Systems", "Execution", "Execution", "Execution", "Execution", 
"Execution", "Execution", "Execution", "Execution", "People/Associate", 
"People/Associate", "Execution", "Systems", "Execution", "Execution", 
"People/Associate", "People/Associate", "Execution"), Postive.or.Negative = c(1L, 
-1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 
-1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 
-1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
-1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
-1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 
-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 
-1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

Here is my code for the ggplot and also a picture of the output:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(Journey.Area = factor(Journey.Area, 
                               levels = c("Getting Assistance", "Returning", "Using Product", "Installing", 
                                          "Delivery", "Pickup", "Anticipating", "Buying", 
                                          "Deciding How to Buy", "Browsing"))) %>%
  count(Journey.Area, Experience.Framework, 
        wt = Postive.or.Negative, name = "Positive.or.Negative") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Positive.or.Negative, Journey.Area, fill = Experience.Framework)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-15, 15), labels = abs) + labs(x = 'Negative Sentiment        Positive Sentiment', y="Customer Journey Area", fill="User Experience Framework") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12)) + ggtitle("Customer Sentiment Matrix") + theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 14))
```

Here is the plot. You'll notice that "Execution" is not being plotted for "Browsing" Another example is "Systems" is not being plotted for "Deciding How to Buy". When you look at my dput, there is data for these but for some reason it's not showing up.
I've double checked spelling and all, but nothing. Any thoughts on how to fix?

[image: ggplot missing data]

Comment: Have a look at your data. `df %>% filter(Journey.Area == "Browsing", Experience.Framework == "Execution")` shows two rows--one with `1` one with `-1`. With your weighted count, those get summed to 0. 0s don't show up in bar charts. You could use `geom_point()` if you want to see the 0s.

Comment: From the data, the sum of is 0, therefore not plotted. Whereas Browsing - People/Associate is -1 and Systems is -2

Comment: That would do it!...Thanks so much!